# How can a database update trigger a unique error?

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to update an item in a database, like this:

```
attribute.update({value: value});
```

But I get this error:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: Validation error
```

This is the sql that is running:

```
UPDATE `userAttributes` 
   SET `userId`=1,
       `updatedAt`='2016-07-04 16:37:29.183 +00:00' 
WHERE `id` IN (1)
```

No properties in the data-model are unique. What does this error mean and what is causing it?

Comment: Could you post your model definitions as well? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any unique constraint on `userAttributes`

Comment: I have not. Thanks though.

Comment: Indexes? What is your database? SQLite? Something else?

Comment: No indexes except ID, yes SQLite?

Comment: can you share the `js` code where you associate `userAttributes` and `user`?